# What is the different between UI Automator and driver.swipe via appium

Tags: android, scroll, appium, ui-automation

I wonder what is the different between `UI Automator` and `driver.swipe` when I try to find element(s) with scroll.

With `UI Automator` I can scroll and find `element\elements` with `text\text contains\id\text starts with`:

```
new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text("' + text + '").instance(0))')
```

And with `driver.swipe` is with `x` and `y`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different is in implementation and purpose:

**UIAutomator**

- Searching for element via UIAutomator allows to actually scroll view up/down to the searchable element. First of all, it is a search action, you can use it for scrolling if you have a scrollable view and know element inside of it. So it requires:
- View with `scrollable=true` attribute
- Know element id, text, etc. to locate it
- Can't use coordinates
- Fails if element is not found
- Not precise, stops scrolling as soon as element is found

```
MobileElement firstClickableEl = driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().clickable(true)"))
MobileElement elementInView = driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text("' + text + '").instance(0))')
"))
```

[More](http://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/android-uiautomator/) information

**Actions API**

Actions API is used for different gestures like touch, tap, drag&drop, [swipe](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/bcca20276191f98d9293974b6430cb97cb5e465c/src/test/java/io/appium/java_client/android/AndroidTouchTest.java#L172-L191), etc.

- no need to locate elements
- Can use both coordinates and elements
- More precise if you pass the right coordinates

```
TouchAction swipe = new TouchAction(driver)
    .press(element(images.get(2),-10, center.y - location.y))
    .waitAction(waitOptions(ofSeconds(2)))
    .moveTo(element(gallery,10,center.y - location.y))
    .release();
swipe.perform();
```

[More](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/touch-actions/) information

Comment: 2 questions:
1. Is UI Automator good for iOS too?
2. Would it be correct to say that with the help of UI Automator there is more flexibility? (Search using text, text contains, text starts with, id, regex)

Comment: 1. UIAutomator is Android-only. You can check iOS native options. 2. It really depends on your goals: if you want swipe to an element in view, use UIAutomator; if you want to check swiping functionality/ can't identify a target element, use Actions API. They both are flexible enough within their functionality scope. I use both in the same project, so don't limit yourself